# Drupal hook_menu_alter system error

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-hooks

Using the following code:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    if (isset($items['node/add/page'])) {
        $items['node/add/page']['access arguments'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> warning: Missing argument 1 for node_access() in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/modules/node/node.module on line
>   2011.

The code actually works and does what I need it to do but the error concerns me and confuses my site users.

I am not sure what the issue is or how to resolve it. Can anyone offer some assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`access arguments` needs to be an array:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['node/add/page'])) {
    $items['node/add/page']['access arguments'] = array();
  }
}
```

If you're trying to deny access to your page to absolutely anyone you should use the `access callback` key instead:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['node/add/page'])) {
    $items['node/add/page']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed my problem.